# Is a San Andreas volcano possible?

Tags: volcanology, tectonics, transform-fault

This question is, in part, inspired from the 1997 Hollywood movie [Volcano](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120461/), where a fictional volcano erupted out of the La Brea Tar Pits in Los Angeles.

The [San Andreas Fault](http://geology.com/articles/san-andreas-fault.shtml) is a transform fault plate boundary (see image below):

[image]

Image from the [USGS Glossary entry for transform faults](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/learn/glossary/?term=transform%20fault), with a definition:

> A transform fault is a special variety of strike-slip fault that accommodates relative horizontal slip between other tectonic elements, such as oceanic crustal plates.

A specific type of transform fault is a 'leaky transform fault', which according to a source used on its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_transform_fault) describes the tectonic movement at this type of faulting as being:

> In addition to the regular strike-slip motion observed at transform boundaries, an oblique extensional component is present, resulting in motion of the plates that is not parallel to the plate boundary.

Illustrated below:

[image]

**Is there any evidence that oblique tectonic movement occurs along the San Andreas Fault?**

**Hence, is a San Andreas volcano possible?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. In fact there are already volcanos associated with the San Andreas fault system.

[Neenach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neenach_Volcano) is an extinct Miocene volcano split in half by the San Andreas fault. [Garry Hayes](https://twitter.com/geotripper) wrote a nice blog post about this volcano system: *[A Volcano Sundered: A Field Trip Along the San Andreas Fault](http://geotripper.blogspot.ca/2009/11/volcano-sundered-field-trip-along-san.html)*.

If you'll allow some latitude in what counts as 'a San Andreas volcano', then there is active volcanism too. [The Salton Buttes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salton_Buttes) are a group of rhyolitic volcanos in the [Brawley Seismic Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brawley_Seismic_Zone), a set of oblique transform faults — actually in the axis of the active Gulf of California rift — on the south-east shore of the Salton Sea. You can see them in this Google Maps image (on the right; the big fields are 800 m across):

[image: The Imperial Valley faults and the Salton Buttes]

The Space Shuttle photo (left) of the Imperial Valley [annotated by the USGS](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/research/salton/) shows the relationship between the San Andreas fault, about 5 km from the volcanos, the Brawley Seismic Zone (BSZ), and the Imperial Fault to the south. At this scale, it's essentially one big fault system.